# Nuxt Js - Script loaded just once during initial page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I have a static website designed already and I am converting to Nuxt js as the website needs to be interactive. After I run my Nuxt server "npm run build...npm run start" the scripts are loaded and my carousel/slides works fine. When I navigate using nuxt-link to the next page, slides/carousel doesn't work again. I think the issue is that my scripts are only loaded initially when loaded from the server.

in my nuxt.config.js file, I have included the js in head tag following the api docs both globally and in my component but its the same

```
head: {
    script: [
        /* external javascripts */
        { src: 'js/jquery.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/bootstrap.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/wow.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/jquery.backTop.min.js', body: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/waypoints.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/waypoints-sticky.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/owl.carousel.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/jquery.counterup.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/venobox.min.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true },
        { src: 'js/custom-scripts.js', body: true, async: true, defer: true }
      ],
}
```

going through some resource online, I have added **async: true and defer: true**, but it all seem to be the same

the images below are screenshots of how the testimonial carousel looks at page load and after nuxt-link navigation
[image: Image at Initial page load]

[image: Image after nuxt-link navigation]

Please any suggestion on how to fix this?
Thanks a lot

PS: When I reload the page entirely by reloading the tab, the slides works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually used vue carousel to fix the slides.
`npm install vue-carousel` 
Then I created a vue-carousel.js file in my plugins folder

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueCarousel from 'vue-carousel';

Vue.use(VueCarousel);
```

In my nuxt.config.js file, I imported my plugin

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-carousel.js', ssr: false },
  ]
```

finally in my .vue file

```
<carousel :per-page-custom="[[200, 1], [768, 2]]">
    <slide>
      Slide 1 Content
    </slide>
    <slide>
      Slide 2 Content
    </slide>
  </carousel>
```

replacing the content of the slides, my final output

[image: Fina Output]